# SQL server express localDB can access from two app process?

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I read a lot about that, but I still stay in the foggy. there some terms confuse. User? Instance? and so on. I don't care learning it, but I try figure up, what follow claim is true:

1. Can localDB can start as service?
2. Can LocalDB can access at the same time from two app or two instance of the same app?
3. Can I make connection from process that not start the LocalDB. For example: I have App that opened two windows at separate process.
4. Have any other way to access simultaneity by multiple local app to the same DB file?

It's seem LocalDB is better way for distributed app due his faster installation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use SQL Server Express instead, the installation can be easily made unattended, and it will enable any process, even on other machines, to have "simultaneous" access to the database.